# How to copy selected records from one DynamoDB table to another?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, datatable, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have two DynamoDB tables, I want to copy just 100 records out of 5000 to another table. Is there any way to do so? I currently have a script which copies the entire contents of the table but I just need a few records to be copied.

Does AWS have any way to do so? Here is the script that I am currently using:

```
import boto3
import os
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    from datetime import datetime
    dynamotargetclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='****', ## Account key
        aws_access_key_id='****',
        aws_secret_access_key='****')
    
    dynamoclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='***',   ##UAT  Account key
        aws_access_key_id='****',
        aws_secret_access_key='****')

    #print ("Scanning and replicating Table Name : " + table)
    dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
    print (dateTimeObj)

    dynamopaginator = dynamoclient.get_paginator('scan')
    
    tabname= '****'
    
    targettabname= '****'
    dynamoresponse = dynamopaginator.paginate(
        TableName=tabname,
        Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
        ReturnConsumedCapacity='NONE',
        ConsistentRead=True
    )
    for page in dynamoresponse:
        for item in page['Items']:
            dynamotargetclient.put_item(
                TableName=targettabname,
                Item=item
            )
            
    print ("Replication complete for Table Name : " + targettabname)
    print (datetime.now())
```

Comment: A script seems appropriate for this task.  Not a large amount of data and can be run very quickly.